# Team Build Notifications - Status of a Build has changed

Tags: tfs, build, notifications

I need some help with the Team Alerts. I know how to setup the Team alerts and it works for situations like:

- Build done
- My Build done
- Build failed
- My Build failed
- and so on

What I would like to cover is the following situation:

1. A Build failed. -> Users get a Mail that it failed.
2. Build gets fixed. -> Users get a Mail that the Build got fixed.
3. Build gets NOT fixed. -> Users do not get a Mail that is telling them, that the build is still broken.

So I would like to have Team alerts based on the Build Status and if it changes.
I don´t want a mail per good build and a mail per broken build.
I want mails for Builds that change the Build Status from Broken to Succeed and from Succeed to broken.

Is that even possible? I only see Build quality but that has nothing to do with the status.

Comment: Out-of-the-box there is no concept of "status of a build definition". You can get it, with some external tool or customizing your build script. Which works better for you?

Comment: You can track build status with an app like [CatLight build monitor](https://catlight.io) that works quite similarly to what you described, but without emails - it shows notifications directly on the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Builds have a value called "build quality" that you can change. If you add values of "fixed" and "not fixed" you can get alerts based on this value changing.

Then all you have to do is get folks to update the value...